# What kind of properties characterise "constant curvature" for a general geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, cartan-geometry

> **Question:** What are some characteristic properties of constant curvature or flat spaces?

Some motivation and context:

There are a lot of things on manifolds that are called geometric structures, like pseudo-Riemannian geometry or conformal geometry. All of the examples I know (minus symplectic geometry, which is "not geometry") fit into the framework of a Cartan geometry, but there are more general formulations around that I am not familiar with.

> Briefly, a Cartan geometry modelled on a homogenous space $G/P$ is a principal bundle $P\to E\to M$ together with a parallelism $\omega: TE\to\mathfrak g$ as well as some compatibility conditions.
>
> Here one can define a curvature as a $\mathfrak g$-valued two form on $E$:
>   $$\kappa_x[v,w]= d\omega_x(v,w)-[\omega_x(v),\omega_x(w)]_\mathfrak{g}.$$
>   With the parallelism $\omega$ this is recast to be a function $E\to \mathrm{Lin}(\Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g},\mathfrak g)$. It is natural to say that the space has constant curvature if the curvature is constant, or that the space is flat if the curvature is zero.
>
> A remark about this is that $\mathrm{Lin}(\Lambda^2 \mathfrak g, \mathfrak g)$ carries a representation of $P$ from the adjoint action. The curvature as defined above is equivariant wrt this representation, ie $\kappa(x\cdot p)=\rho(p^{-1})\cdot\kappa(x)$. If the function $\kappa$ is to be constant it must take on values in trivial sub-representations in $\mathrm{Lin}(\Lambda^2\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g})$, which with our definition means that there might be geometries with no non-flat constant curvature realisations.

I'm interested in trying to recover "synthetic" properties of constant curvature spaces from this definition in order to see that it is a good definition. One thing that is clear is that we will have enough Killing fields (fields that flow via automorphisms) to explore a neighbourhood of any point in the manifold, but this is a property that locally homogenous manifolds also have. Beyond this we also have the "maximum possible" amount of local isotropies at any point.

But I don't really have much more intuition available with regards to what I should expect for a constant curvature space.

Comment: What do you mean for the curvature of a Cartan geometry to be constant? For a general Cartan geometry $(\mathcal G, \omega)$ of type $(G, P)$, the curvature is a section of $\bigwedge^2 T^* \mathcal G \otimes \mathfrak g$. In the special case of Riemannian geometry, we can extract from this section the usual curvature tensor $R_{ab}{}^c{}_d \in \Gamma(\bigwedge^2 T^*M \otimes \operatorname{End}(TM))$ and contract twice (once with the metric) to produce the scalar curvature. But for some Cartan geometries one can't mimic this process to produce from the curvature an unweighted scalar function.

Comment: I second Travis' request. For instance, suppose that we have  conformal or projective structures. I understand what flatness means but constant curvature is utterly unclear to me in these cases.

Comment: Even in Riemannian geometry, there are different notions of "constant curvature", at least you have constant sectional curvature (which characterizes space-forms), covariantly constant curvature (which characterizes locally symmetric spaces) and constant scalar curvature (which probably is to weak to count as a condition of constant curvature). The condition of covariantly constant curvature generalizes to all geometric structures admitting an appropriate canonical connection, for the other conditions, this is less clear.

Comment: @Travis the Cartan connection gives you a parallelism of the bundle $P\to E\to M$. You can use this to recast $V$ valued $n$-forms on the total space $E$ as maps $E\to \mathrm{Lin}(\Lambda^n \mathfrak{g}, V)$. Specifically this makes the curvature into a function $E\to \mathrm{Lin}(\Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g})$. The target space carries a $P$ representation and this function is equivariant wrt to right-multiplication with $P$ on $E$ and the representation. This function being constant is what I mean with "constant curvature".

Comment: @AndreasCap I have always understood "constant curvature" in the Riemannian setting to be that the sectional curvature at each point does not depend on the hyperplane that we feed it and that the sectional curvature (which is now a number) doesn't vary from point to point. This seemed the most natural definition to me, and people around me talk a lot about constant curvature so I assumed it is common notion, but I'm not really experienced with this topic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan in part that is also what I want to know :) I also don't know what flatness means for other geometries.

Comment: I agree that "constant sectional curvature" is the most common notion of "constant curvature", but it is an intricate notion (depending a lot on pculiarities of Riemannian geometry). Your idea to require constant curvature function does not work out, since $P$-equivariancy contradicts being constant unless there is a trivial representation contained in $Lin(\Lambda^2\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g)$. Flatness on the other hand, is easy to characterize for Cartan geometries, it just means local isomorphism to the homogeneous model.

Comment: @AndreasCap such "isotropic points" in $\mathrm{Lin}(\Lambda^2\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g})$ are necessary, yes. Such points that are non-zero do exist, at least in the case of psuedo-Riemannian geometry. When I tested a couple of constant curvature metrics like the Killing form on $SL_2$ I found that the curvature takes values on such points.

Comment: That's true, but they don't exist for conformal and projective structures and, more generally, for parabolic geometries.

Comment: @AndreasCap thank you for your helpful and interesting comments. I am interested in trying to prove what you said, is there a simple criterium for what a parabolic geometry is? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_geometry_(differential_geometry)) leads me to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_subgroup) definition of parabolic groups, which I have no hope being able to use in this context.

Comment: The definition of parabolic subgroups (and hence of parabolic geometries) is a bit intricate and uses the structure theory of semisimple Lie algebras. And from the definition it is quite a long way to the statement that you are interested in. Basically, one can extract a component of the Cartan curvature in the parabolic case, called the harmonic curvature, whose vanishing is equivalent to vanishing of the full Cartan curvature. The values of the harmonic curvature lie in a subspace that is a notrivial irreducible representation and hence has no isotropic point.